# Databinding: does not contain a property with the name 'CategoryId' error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am going through a tutorial and trying out something when I got this error with this line, can someone advice, thanks:

```
<ItemTemplate>               

<a class='MostPopularItemText' href='ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%# Eval("ProductId") %>&&CategoryId=<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>'><%# Eval("ModelName") %></a><br />                 

</ItemTemplate>
```

Somethings not right with 'CategoryId' because it will work if I take it out:

```
<aclass='MostPopularItemText'href='ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%# Eval("ProductId") %>&&CategoryId=<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>'><%# Eval("ModelName") %></a><br/>
```

to

```
<aclass='MostPopularItemText'href='ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'><%# Eval("ModelName") %></a><br/>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
private void WriteAlsoPurchased(int currentProduct)

{

   using (CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities())

    {

       try

          {

            var v = db.SelectPurchasedWithProducts(currentProduct);

                   RepeaterItemsList.DataSource = v;

                   RepeaterItemsList.DataBind();

           }

       catch (Exception exp)

           {

            throw new Exception("ERROR: Unable to Write Also Purchased - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);  <------location where the exception is thrown

            }

      }

}
```

**'SelectPurchasedWithProducts' Store Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE

dbo.SelectPurchasedWithProducts

@ProductID int

AS

SELECT TOP 5 

OrderDetails.ProductID,

Products.CategoryID,

Products.ModelName,



SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) as TotalNum

FROM

    OrderDetails

INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID

WHERE

  OrderID IN 

(

/* This inner query should retrieve all orders that have contained the productID */

SELECT DISTINCT OrderID 

FROM OrderDetails

WHERE ProductID = @ProductID

)

AND

OrderDetails.ProductID != @ProductID 

GROUP BY

OrderDetails.ProductID, Products.CategoryID, Products.ModelName 

ORDER BY

TotalNum DESC

RETURN
```

Comment: I just realise that if I change everything(stored proc, inline code and codebehind) from 'ModelName' to 'ModelNumber' which is also a valid field in my table,  I still get an error as seen below which still mentions 'ModelName' which means there is some mysterious location I still need to alter. This could be a lead to my main 'CategoryId' issue.
Exception:
"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CommerceModel.SelectPurchasedWithProducts_Result'. A member of the type, 'ModelName', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Answer (score 2):

Your property is named CategoryID not CategoryId

```
<%# Eval("CategoryId")  %>
```

Should read

```
<%# Eval("CategoryID")  %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- How about <%# Eval("Products.CategoryId") %>?
- Are the two ampersands causing an issue?  &&CategoryId=...
- Also, try binding CategoryId outside of the link by itself and verify that the value outputs.  Your code looks good to me that's why I have to wonder if it's just the way your link is structured.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the 2 ampersands are fine, I can do this &&CategoryId=555'> Tried point no. 1 & 3 too, doesn't help too unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it, after updating the S Proc, I have to access my Model Browser Function, expand the EntityContainer, enter the Function Imports and click on Update button. I hope this helps those with either the

"Databinding: does not contain a property with the name 'xxx' error."
 or 
"A member of the type, 'xxx', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

after everything seem to be in place.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I don't quite get what you mean. Specifically :**I have to access my Model Browser Function, expand the EntityContainer, enter the Function Imports and click on Update button.**

Comment: To expand on this: If you changed the SP (by adding a column in the result set, for example) after you imported the object into EntityFramework, your entities need to be updated.  However, as of VS2015, the "update" doesn't update the complex type.  You need to remove the SP from your entity, then update your edmx to reimport the SP.  You need to remove it from the Model.Store, The function import, and the Complex type. *all 3 places*.